# Best route for multiple user roles with toggleable permissions with React and Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, users, react, redux

What is the best way to create dynamic user roles that can have toggleable permissions?

I am currently creating my very first website which has a react front end with redux toolkit and redux saga and my back end is Django rest framework. Companies will be able to have their own pages on the website, the owner can then create multiple user roles/teams and assign users to each specific role. The owner can also toggle on and off permissions for each specific role as an example whether they have access to seeing specific components and/or whether they can perform CRUD API calls. (This would help as an example for a warehouseman to only CRUD in the warehouse components and for a factory operative to only CRUD in the factory components. But for them both to still be able to see both sides' components and read the data in them without much interaction.)

1. What would be the best way to implement this system?
2. Should I state on the component to do a check in the user state
   whether the user has the specific authorization enabled?
3. Is it possible for this store to be modified externally by someone
   and thus circumvent this authorisation/permission?

Are there any alternative/better ways to implement these permission/limitations?

For the backend, what would be the best route to implement it there, I understand that groups helps in what the user can do in terms of CRUD calls.

Would it be the right thing to do for this case that when the owner toggles the permission for CRUD on a specific component, that the users in that user role would be added to the group that enables CRUD on that specific component?
If I were to do that how would I ensure that whenever that API call is made, that it checks whether the user is in that group or not? I will definitely look more into this if this is recommended, a pointer would be sincerely appreciated!

All of that does seem convoluted as well, what would be the best approach for me to take here and are there any resources for me to further study and implement? Are there any other suggestions you may have that I can implement rather than doing what I am currently attempting?

Apologies for the newbie questions, I have found it quite difficult to combine the two as I have not found the best route to take here. Thank you!

Comment: What's so unique about your system that makes the typical solutions insufficient?

Comment: Thank you for the question, unfortunately I havent managed to find out what the typical solutions are other than the one from the MDN tutorial for django. I would perhaps say the toggling on and off of permissions would make it a bit unique actually.

Comment: What made you think that the tutorial you've found is sub-optimal? There aren't that many degrees of freedom in your requirements, neither are they unique — many (most?) multi-tenant SaaS are doing exactly what you describe.